# Can I use speaker wire as a transmission line?

Tags: transmission-line

Speaker wire is really cheap and available everywhere, and it doesn't seem that different to 300 ohm twin lead. It seems to me it would make an excellent balanced transmission line.

What would the approximate impedance and loss be? Can I use a balun / matching transformer at the radio end and then tune the antenna to the speaker wire impedance?

Comment: Speaker wire is not similar to twinlead in that the distance between the wires is very different.  Does your speaker wire have a rated impedance?

Comment: There are impedance calculators out there if you wanted to test your assertion. You'll have to estimate the dielectric constant. Speaker wire makes a fine transmission line if you split it and make ladder line from it. Though, I can't help but think that If speaker wire as-is was a Good Enough transmission line, cheap hams would already be using it.

Comment: Well, it's [been a fad](https://www.venhaus1.com/diycatfivecables.html) in [audiophile circles](https://techtalk.parts-express.com/forum/tech-talk-forum/1319445-cat-5-ethernet-as-speaker-wire) for [some years now](https://www.diyaudio.com/community/threads/cat-5-speaker-cable-thoughts.267738/), to build speaker cables out of Cat5 UTP ethernet. High-speed digital and radio are very different payloads, of course, but how is Cat5 UTP as transmission wire? ...I bet not very good.

Comment: cat5e is I think 100 ohms and very stable.  A 2:1 balun would make that good for coax.  Unfortunately, the current carrying capacity of the wires is pretty small, so you might be limited to QRP.

Comment: So-called audiophiles should not be held up as paragons of experimental and practical physics.

Comment: I second cate5 for QRP work. It's also twisted which helps reject common mode signals. You can also use the left over to both 2:1 and  a 1 :1 choke using two pairs in parallel for a 50 Ohm match. I have made two baluns like this with small FT43 toroids and they work well. You can dumpster dive cat5e. I've never tried cat5e as a trans line though. I bought the expensive 450 Ohm window line. For SSB at 5 watts coax is not my first choice.

Comment: I recall many years ago that a ham buddy of mine used 75 ohm twinlead to drive a dipole. It looked a lot like speaker wire, size-wise. I presume the close spacing is responsible for the reduced impedance compared to more common twinleads. (There are still some references to 75 ohm twinlead around, so it may still be available.) Since we're all about experimenting, give it a try.

Comment: Checking a range of prices, speaker wire is not really cheap compared to other solutions designed for antennas such as 300 ohm or 450 ohm ladder line.  In fact, DX Engineering has ladder line available for costs that overlap and compare nicely to the 100 foot rolls of speaker wire (assuming 100 foot lengths).  Shop around, I actually sold 250 foot of 450 ohm ladder line for $50 a year ago -- I was not trying to get highest price though, just trying to get rid of it rather than throw it away.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I can think of a reason expect this not to work very well. The impedance of twin-lead transmission line is dependent on the *ratio between*

- the diameter of the conductors, and
- the distance between their centers.

In twin-lead or any parallel-conductor transmission line, the insulation is designed to keep that distance stable. On the other hand, in speaker wire, the insulation is usually quite soft, and a small amount (<1 mm) of incidental squishing of the cable will quite significantly change the distance between the conductors, and thus the impedance.

But, that's a *theoretical* answer, on why we don't in general use cheap speaker wire or lamp-cord for transmission lines. What about in practice?

Well, I've got a piece of speaker wire handy (30 ft or so, 16 AWG). I unplugged it from my speaker and plugged it into a resistance decade box and my antenna analyzer, and made some measurements. Impedance, 0-30 MHz:

[image: Impedance chart]

So, an adequate piece of transmission line around 110 Ω.

Does it have obvious impedance discontinuities measured in my analyzer's "TDR" mode?

[image: TDR chart]

Not very much! (The spike on the left end is the connection to the analyzer, and the wiggle on the right is the connection to the termination.)

I'd guess that the practical reasons not to use speaker wire are:

- It's not a standard impedance, so you'd need matching on both ends
- Any *particular* product might have a different impedance
- It's not coax, so you have to treat it like any twin-lead and keep it away from other things, but people generally prefer coax unless they're building a high-performance HF station, at which point why use the cheap stuff?

Comment: But if you were desperate or poor, you could use speaker wire ... with matching at both ends ... and get good results.

Comment: Matching at both ends might cost more than using the correct wire with a rated impedance.

Comment: To be fair, you might only need impedance matching at the radio if the antenna can be tuned to the impedance of the line, such as a custom dipole.

Answer (score 8):

It depends substantially on the particular speaker wire — available gauges range from 14-2 to 22-2, insulation materials and spacing vary, and the impedance is probably somewhere between 80 and 150 ohms, depending. The loss will be worse than 300-ohm ladder line because of the lower impedance (meaning higher current for a given power), because speaker wire has a higher "fill factor" (percentage of the space between conductors occupied by insulator rather than air), and because the insulator is usually PVC (which is much lossier than PE or PTFE), and will probably be on a par with very cheap coax.

But since there's no standardization for this stuff in terms of its RF properties, you can't really tell what you'll get from a particular roll without buying it and measuring it. It's probably fine for a "whatever dipole" but not for any design that requires careful impedance matching.

Comment: Great answer. I've been curious about the use of PTFE. I like  PTFE for it's heat tolerance and abrasion resistance but didn't realize it also helps with loss. I've made a few baluns with it and they work really well.

Comment: You are right on about the loss because of the poor dielectric properties of the insulation. I didn't  search, but I've read about many tests confirming this.

Comment: How about audiophile-grade speaker wire? Those seem to have negative impedance and even add stuff that isn't on the original recording.

Answer (score -1):

1. You can use any type of wire to construct twinlead type feedline. Back in the day before coax was popular, odd pieces of scrounged wire, lampcord, speaker wire, even extension cord was used with success.
2. The impedance of the feedline is unimportant. If directly connecting twinlead to a halfwave dipole (two quarter wave sections fed in the center usually but not always), there will be an impedance mismatch at the feedpoint, since a half wave dipole AT ITS RESONANT FREQUENCY will be approximately 72 ohms, depending on its height above ground. This will create reflected power in the feedline which u-turns at the transmitter and bounces up and down the feedline. Since it is a high impedance feedline, the voltage is high and the current is low, resulting in low I squared R losses. Using 300 ohm tv twinlead, or audiophile wire is a waste of money. Just get your hands on some cheap spools of wire and fabricate a twinlead feedline, making sure to install it properly by keeping it a few inches away from metal objects and twisting it every couple of feet to prevent it oscillating in the wind. Coax is inherently lossy (especially in long lengths) because of the higher currents in it. The nice thing about is that you can make your own for low cost. If you go out and buy 200 feet of "low loss" coax it will cost a packet. If you want a multi-band dipole, this is easily accomplished with twinlead feedline coming down to some type of matching arrangement at the transmitter to convert the high impedance line to the 50 ohms the transmitter would like to see. If you use coax expecting to use it on multiple bands you will have a great deal of difficulty, and the losses on some frequencies will be very large. If you refer to any edition of the ARRL Amateur's Handbook you will find very concise explanations of antenna and feedline basics. Fianlly - stop obsessing over SWR!
   I hope this helps.
   Added Oct 17 -
   Here's another idea if you have some tv twinlead lying around. Make a folded dipole for the lowest frequency you will operate on, and feed it with the 300 ohm twinlead. You will have a very close impedance match at the feedpoint, hence low reflected power in the feedline, reducing losses even more. Simply connect the feedline to a transmatch as usual. The 300 feedline will be able to handle 300 watts or more due to the low current. The folded dipole will also give a little more gain than a straight dipole. Easy to make with cheap materials! Covers multiple bands. Keep the coax between transmitter and tuner as short as possible. Disconnect and short out when electrical storms are approaching!